# Vectorization in Matlab to speed up expensive loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How can I speed up the following MATLAB code, using vectorization? Right now the single line in the loop is taking hours to run for the case `upper = 1e7`.

Here is the commented code with sample output:

```
p = 8;
lower = 1;
upper = 1e1;
n = setdiff(lower:upper,primes(upper)); % contains composite numbers between lower + upper
x = ones(length(n),p); % Preallocated 2-D array of ones

% This loop stores the unique prime factors of each composite
% number from 1 to n, in each row of x. Since the rows will have
% varying lengths, the rows are padded with ones at the end.

for i = 1:length(n)
    x(i,:) = [unique(factor(n(i))) ones(1,p-length(unique(factor(n(i)))))];
end
```

**output:**

```
x =

 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     3     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 2     5     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

For example, the last row contains the prime factors of 10, if we ignore the ones. I have made the matrix 8 columns wide to account for the many prime factors of numbers up to 10 million.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could use a `parfor` loop if you have access to the Parallel Computing toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not vectorization, but this version of the loop will save about half of the time:

```
for k = 1:numel(n)
    tmp = unique(factor(n(k)));
    x(k,1:numel(tmp)) = tmp;
end
```

Here is a quick benchmark for this:

[image: get prime]

```
function t = getPrimeTime
lower = 1;
upper = 2.^(1:8);
t = zeros(numel(upper),2);
for k = 1:numel(upper)
    n = setdiff(lower:upper(k),primes(upper(k))); % contains composite numbers between lower to upper
    t(k,1) = timeit(@() getPrime1(n));
    t(k,2) = timeit(@() getPrime2(n));
    disp(k)
end
p = plot(log2(upper),log10(t));
p(1).Marker = 'o';
p(2).Marker = '*';
xlabel('log_2(range of numbers)')
ylabel('log(time (sec))')
legend({'getPrime1','getPrime2'})
end

function x = getPrime1(n) % the originel function
p = 8;
x = ones(length(n),p); % Preallocated 2-D array of ones
for k = 1:length(n)
    x(k,:) = [unique(factor(n(k))) ones(1,p-length(unique(factor(n(k)))))];
end
end

function x = getPrime2(n)
p = 8;
x = ones(numel(n),p); % Preallocated 2-D array of ones
for k = 1:numel(n)
    tmp = unique(factor(n(k)));
    x(k,1:numel(tmp)) = tmp;
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
p = 8;
lower = 1;
upper = 1e1;
p = 8;
q = primes(upper);
n = setdiff(lower:upper, q);
x = bsxfun(@times, q, ~bsxfun(@mod, n(:), q));
x(~x) = inf;
x = sort(x,2);
x(isinf(x)) = 1;
x = [x ones(size(x,1), p-size(x,2))];
```

This seems to be faster than the other two options (but is uses more memory). Borrowing [EBH's benchmarking code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40365563/2586922):

[image]

```
function t = getPrimeTime
lower = 1;
upper = 2.^(1:12);
t = zeros(numel(upper),3);
for k = 1:numel(upper)
    n = setdiff(lower:upper(k),primes(upper(k)));
    t(k,1) = timeit(@() getPrime1(n));
    t(k,2) = timeit(@() getPrime2(n));
    t(k,3) = timeit(@() getPrime3(n));
    disp(k)
end
p = plot(log2(upper),log10(t));
p(1).Marker = 'o';
p(2).Marker = '*';
p(3).Marker = '^';
xlabel('log_2(range of numbers)')
ylabel('log(time (sec))')
legend({'getPrime1','getPrime2','getPrime3'})
grid on
end

function x = getPrime1(n) % the originel function
p = 8;
x = ones(length(n),p); % Preallocated 2-D array of ones
for k = 1:length(n)
    x(k,:) = [unique(factor(n(k))) ones(1,p-length(unique(factor(n(k)))))];
end
end

function x = getPrime2(n)
p = 8;
x = ones(numel(n),p); % Preallocated 2-D array of ones
for k = 1:numel(n)
    tmp = unique(factor(n(k)));
    x(k,1:numel(tmp)) = tmp;
end
end

function x = getPrime3(n) % Approach in this answer
p = 8;
q = primes(max(n));
x = bsxfun(@times, q, ~bsxfun(@mod, n(:), q));
x(~x) = inf;
x = sort(x,2);
x(isinf(x)) = 1;
x = [x ones(size(x,1), p-size(x,2))];
end
```

Comment: Impressive. Looks like benchmarking can go a long way!

Comment: good idea do you need much of speed improvements? just after `n = setdiff(lower:upper, q);` add  `q = q(q<=sqrt(q(end-1)));`

Comment: You can note in the answer that for large value of `upper` this procedure may be divided to smaller chanks